# Fatal Error: Call To A Member Function Fetch_assoc() on Boolean On My Website

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to take out the game id from the database but I'm having trouble with it. And I do it like this:

```
if(!isset($_GET['round'])){
    $currentgame=$mysql->query('SELECT `value` FROM `info` WHERE `name`="current_game"')->fetch_assoc();
    $currentgame=(int)$currentgame['value'];
```

The error that comes up is

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 85

I have no clue on what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: you have an error in you query. Check for [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all of your code, I'm assuming there's an error thrown by MySQL - possibly to do with the name="current_game"' section.

You should catch all errors when you're performing an action on a MySQL database. The error you're seeing at the moment is from MySQL returning boolean value FALSE.

Add something like this to your code:

```
if (!$currentgame) {
    throw new Exception("Database Error [{$mysql->query->errno}] {$mysql->query->error}");
}
```

This should help you work out what error is being returned.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Database Error [] ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:85 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 85                                                                                       This is the error that its showing me now

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my code - try the edited version

Comment: Sadly im still getting the same error even if i put it before, after, or in the middle of the code. Now i have no clue at what the reason for it might be